# How to call a php script using system in PHPFog

Tags: php, phpfog

I have a php script which needs to run in the background. Currently on my dev box I am running

```
shell_exec("php5-cgi <path>");
```

It works fine. Although, when I pushed my code onto a dedicated phpfog cloud, it seem that the script is not being called. I am unable to find out where the issue is. Is it that exec_shell is not working or php5-cgi command does not exist.

How can I understand better what is going on ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHPFog, but in [Pagoda Box, these are called workers](http://help.pagodabox.com/customer/portal/articles/430779). Not pimping the competition, just giving you my context.

Comment: What is `exec_shell`? PHP function?

Comment: First you should get familiar with documentation: http://docs.phpfog.com/faqs/#sharedvdedicated

Comment: JaredFarrish: Thanks looking at it :)
GabrielSantos: Yes, it is a PHP fuction. 
@dev-null-dweller: I have read it, it does not say anything on how to call a php script using any of the functions though. Just says that they are available in a dedicated sever (which I have)

Answer (score 1):

You might try dropping `5-cgi` from your exec call:

```
exec_shell("php <path>");
```

Additionally, you could use a cron job for this: http://docs.phpfog.com/customize/cron

Create a cron job to run `<path>` on an interval that works for your needs (Assuming path is a php file). PHPFog makes this very easy.

If you are trying to execute a long running task, an not make a browser wait for the result, I recommend queuing in a database table then use a cron job to execute a php script that handles those queued tasks. I would use ajax calls from the client to check the status of the task and then do a page refresh when the task completes.

Comment: This has almost solved my problem. Only issue now is that. When I run "php <path>" I do not have the apache environment exposed to that script.

Comment: You will have the phpfog environment variables when you run the script with the cron job interface.